# Clone directory tree, but certain branches only

Tags: windows, file-management, windows-10

I have a directory tree and I would like to clone it to another disk, but not the whole tree, just certain files and directories, keeping their relative paths.

Like (** means the file/directory is chosen for copying)

```
|_ dir1
|__ **dir2**
|___ file1
|___ file2
|__ dir3
|___ **file4**
|___ file5
|__ dir4
```

Would create the following copy:

```
|_ dir1
|__ dir2
|___ file1
|___ file2
|__ dir3
|___ file4
```

The best interface would be tree view with checkboxes of which files and directories to copy.

Is there a piece of software that does this?